# SSIS Logging: Enable/Disable Logging Using Variable Instead of Re-Deployment

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS Package, call it `PackageA`.  Sometimes, I want to have it logging to  a text file, while other times, I do not.  My initial though was to have the package check a table, then use a variable/expression to enable/disable logging.  I am assuming this is not possible?

My work around is to create a "master" package, `PackageB`, with a SQL task to get whether or not to enable logging.  `PackageB` would call `PackageA1` or `PackageA2` depending on the value--`PackageA1` would be `PackageA` deployed with logging enabled and `PackageA2` would be `PackageA` deployed with logging disabled.

That makes deployment a hassle and easy to mess up, however. Is there any way to accomplish, at the very least, something similar to what I am looking for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Packages have `LoggingMode` property, which you can change when you run package using GUI or `dtexec` command line switch: ([more info](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2010/01/05/how-do-i-disable-all-logging-on-my-packages.aspx))

```
dtexec /f "C:\Package.dtsx" /set "\Package.Properties[LoggingMode];2"
```

If you use `SSIS 2012` and `Project Deployment Model` you can also set `LOGGING_LEVEL` parameter from `None` to `Verbose` by using for example `catalog.set_execution_parameter_value` stored procedure ([more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff877990.aspx)).

Comment: the error occurs when execute the package using dtexec if the package is using log provider for sql server. SSDT is 2015 version

`Error: 2018-07-10 15:22:36.31
   Code: 0xC000F427
   Source: LoadExceptionData
   Description: To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install SSIS log provider for SQL Server of Integration Services or higher.
End Error`